# Fail to statically link against dpdk using meson dependency() directive

Tags: static-linking, dpdk, meson-build

I'm trying to use meson to build dpdk's helloworld example as a standalone application.
I want the application to be linked statically against dpdk libraries.

I've downloaded dpdk 22.07 to `/home/aizrailev/dpdk` and installed it to `/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install` (if dpdk is installed system-wide, everything works fine). Then I go to `/home/aizrailev/dpdk/examples/helloworld` and try to use the following meson.build to build the app (before that, I run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig`):

```
project('dpdk-app', 'c')                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                              
dpdk = dependency('libdpdk', static: true)                                                                                                                                                    
sources = files('main.c')                                                                                                                                                                     
executable('dpdk-app', sources, dependencies: dpdk)
```

Steps to build the app:

```
meson build
cd build/
ninja
```

The following error occurs:

```
[2/2] Linking target dpdk-app
FAILED: dpdk-app 
cc  -o dpdk-app dpdk-app.p/main.c.o -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--whole-archive
-Wl,--start-group /home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_common_cpt.a
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_common_dpaax.a
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_common_iavf.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_common_octeontx.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bus_auxiliary.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bus_dpaa.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bus_fslmc.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bus_ifpga.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bus_pci.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bus_vdev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bus_vmbus.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_common_cnxk.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_common_mlx5.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_common_qat.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_common_sfc_efx.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_mempool_bucket.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_mempool_cnxk.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_mempool_dpaa.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_mempool_dpaa2.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_mempool_octeontx.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_mempool_ring.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_mempool_stack.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_dma_cnxk.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_dma_dpaa.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_dma_dpaa2.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_dma_hisilicon.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_dma_idxd.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_dma_ioat.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_dma_skeleton.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_af_packet.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_ark.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_atlantic.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_avp.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_axgbe.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_bnx2x.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_bnxt.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_bond.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_cnxk.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_cxgbe.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_dpaa.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_dpaa2.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_e1000.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_ena.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_enetc.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_enetfec.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_enic.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_failsafe.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_fm10k.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_hinic.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_hns3.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_i40e.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_iavf.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_ice.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_igc.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_ionic.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_ixgbe.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_kni.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_liquidio.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_memif.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_mlx4.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_mlx5.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_netvsc.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_nfp.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_ngbe.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_null.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_octeontx.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_octeontx_ep.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_pcap.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_pfe.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_qede.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_ring.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_sfc.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_softnic.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_tap.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_thunderx.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_txgbe.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_vdev_netvsc.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_vhost.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_virtio.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net_vmxnet3.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_raw_cnxk_bphy.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_raw_cnxk_gpio.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_raw_dpaa2_cmdif.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_raw_ntb.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_raw_skeleton.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_bcmfs.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_caam_jr.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_ccp.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_cnxk.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_dpaa_sec.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_dpaa2_sec.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_mlx5.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_nitrox.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_null.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_octeontx.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_openssl.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_scheduler.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_crypto_virtio.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_compress_mlx5.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_compress_octeontx.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_compress_zlib.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_regex_mlx5.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_regex_cn9k.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_vdpa_ifc.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_vdpa_mlx5.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_vdpa_sfc.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_event_cnxk.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_event_dlb2.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_event_dpaa.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_event_dpaa2.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_event_dsw.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_event_opdl.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_event_skeleton.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_event_sw.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_event_octeontx.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_baseband_acc100.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_baseband_fpga_5gnr_fec.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_baseband_fpga_lte_fec.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_baseband_la12xx.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_baseband_null.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_baseband_turbo_sw.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_node.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_graph.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_flow_classify.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_pipeline.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_table.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_pdump.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_port.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_fib.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_ipsec.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_vhost.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_stack.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_security.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_sched.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_reorder.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_rib.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_dmadev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_regexdev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_rawdev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_power.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_pcapng.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_member.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_lpm.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_latencystats.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_kni.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_jobstats.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_ip_frag.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_gso.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_gro.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_gpudev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eventdev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_efd.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_distributor.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_cryptodev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_compressdev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_cfgfile.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bpf.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bitratestats.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bbdev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_acl.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_timer.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_hash.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_metrics.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_cmdline.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_pci.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_ethdev.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_meter.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_net.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_mbuf.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_mempool.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_rcu.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_ring.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_eal.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_telemetry.a 
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_kvargs.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
-Wl,--export-dynamic /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/libatomic.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmlx5.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a -ldl -pthread
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmlx4.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libibverbs.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbnxt_re-rdmav34.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcxgb4-rdmav34.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libefa.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhns-rdmav34.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libirdma-rdmav34.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmthca-rdmav34.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libocrdma-rdmav34.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libqedr-rdmav34.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvmw_pvrdma-rdmav34.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhfi1verbs-rdmav34.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libipathverbs-rdmav34.a 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librxe-rdmav34.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsiw-rdmav34.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl-route-3.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnl-3.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjansson.a -Wl,--as-needed -lm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnuma.a
-Wl,--end-group
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a(bpf_filter.o): in function `bpf_validate':
(.text+0x680): multiple definition of `bpf_validate';
/home/aizrailev/dpdk/install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bpf.a(bpf_bpf_validate.c.o):bpf_validate.c:(.text+0x22c0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-sysdeps-unix.o): in function `_dbus_listen_systemd_sockets':
(.text+0x200e): undefined reference to `sd_listen_fds'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x204f): undefined reference to `sd_is_socket'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

However, if I use another meson.build that explicitly calls pkg-config to obtain the flags, then everything is fine:

```
project('dpdk-app', 'c')

pkgconfig = find_program('pkg-config')
cflags_cmd = run_command(pkgconfig, '--cflags', 'libdpdk', check: true)
ldflags_cmd = run_command(pkgconfig, '--static', '--libs', 'libdpdk', check: true)

cflags = cflags_cmd.stdout().split()
ldflags = ldflags_cmd.stdout().split()

sources = files('main.c')
executable('dpdk-app', sources, c_args: cflags, link_args: ldflags)
```

So, the native way for meson to use dependencies leads to an error. Am I missing something? I don't think that invoking pkg-config the way I did in the second meson.build is a good way of doing what I want, but I can't find another options.

Comment: can you please update 1) dpdk version, 2) is the script a cmake, meson or bash file for building used 3) debug or verbose output of the error 4) or least steps to reproduce the error? . Can you first recheck if there is already instance of DPDK in the build machine by `pkg-config --modversion libdpdk`.

Comment: @VipinVarghese,
1) I use the latest dpdk-22.07
2) I use meson to build it
3) I don't know how to make the output more verbose, could you help me with that?
4) Sorry if something is not clear, but I believe that my question contains the steps to reproduce the error -- I provide the meson.build file and the steps that got me to the error
5) There's no other dpdk installed on this machine

Comment: did you get a chance to look into the linking issue as explained in the answers?

Comment: please find the solution shared in the answer. if you find this useful please accept and upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the comments the issue is described as `meson fails to statically build the dpdk application`. But exploring the issue locally does not produce the error with the below meson build file as

```
project('dpdk-app', 'c')

pkgconfig = find_program('pkg-config')
cflags_cmd = run_command(pkgconfig, '--cflags', 'libdpdk', check: true)
ldflags_cmd = run_command(pkgconfig, '--static', '--libs', 'libdpdk', check: true)

cflags = cflags_cmd.stdout().split()
ldflags = ldflags_cmd.stdout().split()

sources = files('main.c')
executable('dpdk-app', sources, c_args: cflags, link_args: ldflags)
```

Steps:

1. copy dpdk example **helloworld** into a custom folder (example: /tmp/mytest)
2. add the **meson.build** to the folder.
3. populate the content with the shared steps as

- use meson-ninja to build the application (***meson build; ninja -C build***)
- ***application get built without any errors***
- run the application using `./build/dpdk-app` (it works)

But we get error, if we use meson build as

```
project('test', 'c')

dpdk = dependency('libdpdk', static: true)
sources = files('main.c')
executable('dpdk-app', sources, dependencies: dpdk, )
```

Closely examining the error logs

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.a(bpf_filter.o): in function `bpf_validate':
(.text+0x460): multiple definition of `bpf_validate'; /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librte_bpf.a(librte_bpf_bpf_validate.c.o):bpf_validate.c:(.text+0x23c0): first defined here
```

The error is coming from librte_bpf.a and libpcap.a.

To work around the issue, please update meson build to

```
project('test', 'c',)

dpdk = dependency('libdpdk', static: true)
sources = files('main.c')
executable('dpdk-app', sources, dependencies: dpdk, link_args : ['-lsystemd', '-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition',])
```

As shared above there is no issue with DPDK or pkg-config if the settings are correct. But actual error is from libraries housing the same function name and code.

Comment: The description of the issue might not be clear, I'm sorry for that. The issue does not occur when using pkg-config manually, it' only with dependency('libdpdk', static: true).
1. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04. I indeed didn't have libsystemd-dev installed, but it didn't help
2. I think this fix wasn't actually added, I don't see it in the repo.
I have PKG_CONFIG_PATH pointing to the locally installed DPDK. Could you please clarify how should I verify it? What tool's `-d` option you mean?
Anyway, manually invoking pkg-config from meson.build works, so I don't think it's pkg-config issue.

Comment: @Arneid `Could you please clarify how should I verify it? What tool's -d option you mean?` please share the meeting link (zoom, googlemeet)

Comment: I've contacted you on LinkedIn, I believe it would be better this way.

Comment: With your suggested meson.build the issues with `bpd_validate` is gone, but the issue with `libdbus` remains:

"
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.a(libdbus_1_la-dbus-sysdeps-unix.o): in function `_dbus_listen_systemd_sockets':
(.text+0x200e): undefined reference to `sd_listen_fds'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x204f): undefined reference to `sd_is_socket'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
"

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not remember that. I am sure that I haven't removed any package since then, and I have libsystemd-dev installed.
Anyway, pkg-config knows where to get `sd_listen_fds`, so why doesn't meson know it?

Comment: please suggest the way to produce the error with _dbus_listen_systemd_sockets. As I unable to do the same. in our last meet, we did install the missing package and this particular error was resolved by using -lsystemd-daemon. please suggest the way to produce the error with _dbus_listen_systemd_sockets. As I unable to do the same. in our last meet, we did install the missing package and this particular error was resolved right?

Comment: sent a debug invite. will love to see the error reproduced with `-lsystemd-daemon`

Comment: It indeed works if I add `-lsystemd` (`libsystemd-daemon` seems to be deprecated, so `-lsystemd-daemon` does not work on my system). Could you please edit your answer for me to accept it? I mean, `link_args` should be `['-lsystemd', '-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition']`.
However, I still do not understand why meson is unable to figure out that we need this flag from the `dependency()` command. I thought that it internally uses pkg-config to get the flags, but then why do I need to specify some `link_args` manually?

Comment: @Arneid can you check the result of pkg-config `pkg-config --cflags --libs --static libdpdk` if it has `-lsystemd`? If it does not there is some other library which might indirectly including `systemd`. But as mentioned on ubutnu 20.04 in my setup I do not see the issue, maybe it is distro dpendend?

Comment: No, the output of the `pkg-config` does not have anything related to `-lsystemd`. Looks like it indeed is something distro-dependant.
Am I correct in my assumption that meson's `dependency()` does not simply call `pkg-config` to obtain the flags?

Comment: `meson's dependency() does not simply call pkg-config to obtain the flags?` yes that is right assumption. updated answer to include systemd

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
I cannot upvote your answer because I lack the reputation point :)